# Which is more appropriate to represent the relations in the code?

Tags: uml, associations, aggregation

I wrote an example code like this:

```
class BaseClass
{
    public virtual void Execute() {}
}

class ClassA: BaseClass
{
    public override void Execute()
    {
        // ClassA Execute implementation
    }
}

class ClassB: BaseClass
{
    private BaseClass _b;

    public ClassB(BaseClass b)
    {
        _b = b;
    }

    public override void Execute()
    {
        _b.Execute();
    }
}
...
ClassB b = new ClassB(new ClassA());
```

I want to draw a proper UML diagram for the above code:

```
<|_______   =  inheritance = "is-a"
<________   =  association
<>_______   =  aggregation = "has-a"
```

Because ClassB actually uses ClassA, my diagram would look like this:

```
    ______|>BaseClass<|_______
   |                          |
ClassA<_____________________ClassB
```

But as we can see from the ClassB constructor it accepts any object which "is-a" BaseClass and additionally holds a reference to it, so maybe I should right away make the diagram look like this:

```
    ______|>BaseClass<|_______
   |             |            |
ClassA           |________<>ClassB
```

Which one is more appropriate or maybe why they both are not appropriate and what would the correct diagram look like?

Any thoughts and reasoning on it will be welcome. Thank you

Edit:
The thing is ClassB inherits from BaseClass, but it also holds a reference to a BaseClass-derived object and uses the object. So in short my problem is: how to depict it on the class diagram?

Comment: @Robert Harvey: thank you for taking the time to answer to my question, but I do not understand why you deleted your post :)

Answer (score 0):

The second diagram is correct. The first one is just a possible "instance" of the second.

Answer (score 0):

I used to work with some methodology prior to U.M.L., that have independant inheritance & composition diagrams. I still separate both diagrams, in U.M.L., unleast there is a very strong reason to mix them.

I suggest to do the same.

Example.

Lets suppouse I'm working with a C++ similar programming language that doesn't support multiple inheritance, but, supports single inheritance.

Lets suppouse I working in an Object & Class Oriented library, & I want to model the classes used in that library, using Class Diagrams, Inheritance & other associations.

Lets suppouse I making my custom Input/Output library with "Stream" classes.

First, I make a base "stream" class:

```
............................................................
.+--------------------------------------------------------+.
.|                    <<abstract>>                        |.
.|                      StreamClass                       |.
.+--------------------------------------------------------+.
.| [+] bool canRead()                         <<virtual>> |.
.| [+] bool canWrite()                        <<virtual>> |.
.| [+] bool canSeek()                         <<virtual>> |.
.| [+] bool isOpen()                          <<virtual>> |.
.| [+] void read(byte[] Buffer, int MaxSize)  <<virtual>> |.
.| [+] void write(byte[] Buffer, int MaxSize) <<virtual>> |.     
.| [+] void open()                            <<virtual>> |.
.| [+] void close()                           <<virtual>> |.
.+--------------------------------------------------------+.
............................................................
```

There is already a filesystem library, that I want to "wrap", with my library,
so I want to make a read-only stream, and a write-only stream class.

```
............................................................
.+--------------------------------------------------------+.
.|                    <<abstract>>                        |.
.|                      StreamClass                       |.
.+--------------------------------------------------------+.
.| [+] bool canRead()                         <<virtual>> |.
.| [+] bool canWrite()                        <<virtual>> |.
.| [+] bool canSeek()                         <<virtual>> |.
.| [+] bool isOpen()                          <<virtual>> |.
.| [+] void read(byte[] Buffer, int MaxSize)  <<virtual>> |.
.| [+] void write(byte[] Buffer, int MaxSize) <<virtual>> |.     
.| [+] void open()                            <<virtual>> |.
.| [+] void close()                           <<virtual>> |.
.+-+------------------------------------------------------+.
...^.........................................................
../.\........................................................
./...\........................................................
.--+--..........................................................
...|............................................................
...|...+---------------------------------------------------------+.
...|...|                     <<concrete>>                        |.
...|...|                    ReaderStreamClass                    |.
...|...+---------------------------------------------------------+.
...|...| [+] bool canRead()                         <<override>> |.
...+---+ [+] bool isOpen()                          <<override>> |.
...|...| [+] void read(byte[] Buffer, int MaxSize)  <<override>> |.
...|...| [+] void open()                            <<override>> |.
...|...| [+] void close()                           <<override>> |.
...|...+---------------------------------------------------------+.
...|...............................................................
...|...+---------------------------------------------------------+.
...|...|                    <<concrete>>                         |.
...|...|                  WriterStreamClass                      |.
...|...+---------------------------------------------------------+.
...|...| [+] bool canWrite()                        <<override>> |.
...+---+ [+] bool isOpen()                          <<override>> |.
.......| [+] void write(byte[] Buffer, int MaxSize) <<override>> |.     
.......| [+] void open()                            <<override>> |.
.......| [+] void close()                           <<override>> |.
.......+---------------------------------------------------------+.
...................................................................
```

Until now, I have modeled a base class, plus 2 subclassses, no big deal.

Later, I need a class that allows both, read & write, but, not at the same, time,
so, I decide to use composition, and create a new class, that its descendant from my stream base class, but, has to composite reader & writer classes, maybe hidden.

Myself, or others programmers that are going to use this class, doesn't know or care,
that have other streams internally.

(1) Inheritance Diagram:

```
............................................................
.+--------------------------------------------------------+.
.|                    <<abstract>>                        |.
.|                      StreamClass                       |.
.+--------------------------------------------------------+.
............................^...................
.........................../.\..................
........................../...\.................
..........................--+--.................
............................|...................
............................|...................
............................|................................
.+--------------------------+------------------------------+.
.|                    <<abstract>>                         |.
.|               ReaderWriterStreamClass                   |.
.+---------------------------------------------------------+.
.| [#] ReaderStreamClass Reader()                          |.
.| [#] WriterStreamClass Writer()                          |.
.+---------------------------------------------------------+.
.| [+] bool canRead()                         <<override>> |.
.| [+] bool canWrite()                        <<override>> |.
.| [+] bool canSeek()                         <<override>> |.
.| [+] bool isOpen()                          <<override>> |.
.| [+] void read(byte[] Buffer, int MaxSize)  <<override>> |.
.| [+] void write(byte[] Buffer, int MaxSize) <<override>> |.     
.| [+] void open()                            <<override>> |.
.| [+] void close()                           <<override>> |.
.+---------------------------------------------------------+.
............................................................
```

(2) Composition Diagram:

```
.............................................................
.........+-------------------------------------------------+.
.........|                    <<abstract>>                 |.
.........|               ReaderWriterStreamClass           |.
.........+-------------------------------------------------+.
..+------+ [#] WriterStreamClass Writer()                  |.
..|..+---+ [#] ReaderStreamClass Reader()                  |.
..|..|...+-------------------------------------------------+.
..|..|.......................................................
..|..|...+-------------------------------------------------+.
..|..+---+                    <<concrete>>                 |.
..|......|               ReaderStreamClass                 |.
..|......+-------------------------------------------------+.
..|..........................................................
..|......+-------------------------------------------------+.
..+------+                    <<concrete>>                 |.
.........|                     WriterStreamClass           |.
.........+-------------------------------------------------+.
.............................................................
```

Cheers.